# Strimzi loading container into aws ecr - error checking push permissions

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-ecr

I am running Apache Kafka on Kubernetes via Strimzi operator.
I am trying to install Kafka Connect with mysql debezium connector.

This is the Connector configuration file:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
  name: my-connect-cluster
  annotations:
    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"
spec:
  version: 3.1.0
  replicas: 1
  bootstrapServers: <bootstrap-server>
  config:
    group.id: connect-cluster
    offset.storage.topic: connect-cluster-offsets
    config.storage.topic: connect-cluster-configs
    status.storage.topic: connect-cluster-status
    config.storage.replication.factor: -1
    offset.storage.replication.factor: -1
    status.storage.replication.factor: -1
  build: 
    output: 
      type: docker
      image: <my-repo-in-ecr>/my-connect-cluster:latest
      pushSecret: ecr-secret
    plugins: 
    - name: debezium-mysql-connector
      artifacts:
      - type: tgz
        url: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql/1.9.0.Final/debezium-connector-mysql-1.9.0.Final-plugin.tar.gz
```

I created the ecr-secret in this way:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry ecr-secret \
  --docker-server=${AWS_ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com \
  --docker-username=AWS \
  --docker-password=$(aws ecr get-login-password) \
  --namespace=default
```

The error I get is the following:

> error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct
> tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again:
> checking push permission for
> "/my-connect-cluster:latest":
> POST https:/ │ │ Stream closed EOF for
> default/my-connect-cluster-connect-build
> (my-connect-cluster-connect-build)

I am not sure what permission I should check. I already tried to use a configuration of the aws cli with a role with admin priviledge just to debug but I got the same error. Any guess?

Comment: Based on the error, `<my-repo-in-ecr>` isn't set? Or you've removed that from the question in the error message? Also Strimzi/Kubernetes shouldn't really matter. You should try `docker push` instead, then pull that rather than building it from k8s. (btw, you've downloaded Postgres connector, not mysql)

Comment: Hi, <my-repo> is set but I did not want to show it. Yes I could push it manually but I would like to use the Strimzi feature that automatically push and pull new version with new plugins inserted. (Thanks for the postgres, I did the worng copy paste I am going to edit my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought some role was missing from the node in the EKS cluster but that is not the case since the only thing needed to authenticate is the information contained in the secret.

The error was actually in the secret creation: two details are very relevant:

1. the --region flag in the aws ecr get-login-password command was missing and therefore a different password was generated.
2. the https:// is needed in front of the docker-server

Below the right command for the secret generation.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry ecr-secret \
  --docker-server=https://${AWS_ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com \
  --docker-username=AWS \
  --docker-password=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1) \
  --namespace=default
```

Comment: The whitespace after --docker-server= needs to be removed.  This was super useful.  Thanks.

Comment: hi @Cr4zyTun4, i tried soemthing very similar to what you did. How do you check if everything went ok? i want to see if it built alright. i tried checking pod logs of the strimzi deployment, but dont see anything related to the connector.

Comment: It should create a connect pod if everything goes well